# When CLR calls Garbage collector in .net?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, clr

Can any one please tell me when Garbage collector gets called? Is it continueously running in background thread? How Garbage collector knows I have to cleans the memory form generations?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx

Comment: When it get called depends on a number of things. Microsoft has great docummentation on the Garbage Collector here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know exaclty if the GC is collecting, you can use this class:

```
public class GCWatcher
{
    protected override void Finalize()
    {
        Debug.Print("GC on the prowl");
        try {
            if (!AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsFinalizingForUnload() && !Environment.HasShutdownStarted) {
                GCWatcher g = new GCWatcher();
            }
        } catch {
            // nothing to do, but in case of error, the GC should continue anyway!
        }
    }
}
```

[Source](http://www.vb-paradise.de/allgemeines/tipps-tricks-und-tutorials/allgemein/65003-garbage-collector/)

The class instantiates itself when it is getting finalized by the GC. Also, it prints a message when the GC kicks in.

Also you can take a look at the links posted in the comments to get a deep-dive into the .NET GC [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The garbage collector runs:

- When your code is trying to allocate memory, and there isn't room enough on the heap.
- When the systems sends a signal to the application to try to use less resources (happens for example when you minimise the application).
- Whenever the garbage collector feels that it would be useful, which for example might be if there is little heap space left and your application is busy doing disk I/O anyway.

Exacly how the garbage collector determines when it should run is an implementation detail, so it can differ between versions of the framework.

The garbage collector doesn't run continuously. When it runs all other threads in the application are frozen so that the garbage collector has sole control over memory.

Answer (score 1):

The Garbage Collector is not running continuously; it runs a single "collection" at a time (which may affect multiple GC "generations").

When it gets called (ignoring `GC.Collect()`) is non-deterministic and I believe is an implementation detail of the CLR, not part of the specification.

That said, the current .NET GC will run whenever a program tries to allocate memory in the managed heap and there is not enough contiguous free memory to do so.  The collection frees up space and defragments the content of the heap, leaving space to perform the allocation.

Anything that survives a Gen0 collection is promoted to Gen1; if there is not enough space in Gen1 for the promoted items then Gen1 is also collected.  The same happens between Gen1 and Gen2.

Answer (score 0):

- When Gen 0 objects will reach ~ 256 KB.
- When Gen 1 objects will reach ~ 2Mb.
- When Gen 2 objects will reach ~ 10Mb.
- When system memory is low.